# Can we manage library permissions in the SharePoint modern library web part?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, permissions, modern-experience

Library web part:

[image]

Library:

[image]

Can we use other functions available in the library in the library web part?

Are there any relevant documents for reference?

Comment: Could be worth explaining what the objective of the question is: what do you aim to achieve? what do you need to achieve as a result of potentially managing permissions in the library web part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a default behavior in SharePoint library web part.

There is no direct option available for **Manage access**.

**Workaround**:

1. Go to SharePoint page where library web part is added.
2. Select File/Folder & click on **Share**

[image]

3. Click on ellipses (...) at the right top corner on **Send link** popup
4. Select **Manage access**.

[image]

**Output**: It will open manage access popup

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you could share the document in the library through the above methods.

If it is the permission of the entire library, you could set permissions in **Library settings>Permissions for the library**:

[image]
[image]

Reference:
[Customize permissions for a SharePoint list or library](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/customize-permissions-for-a-sharepoint-list-or-library-02d770f3-59eb-4910-a608-5f84cc297782)